# Stopping omission of default values in Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3, protobuf.js

I have a proto schema defined as below,

```
message User {
   int64 id = 1;
   bool email_subscribed = 2;
   bool sms_subscribed = 3;
}
```

Now as per official [proto3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), default values are not serialized to save space during wire transmission. But in my case I want to receive whether the client has explicitly set `true/false` for fields `email_subscribed/sms_subscribed` (because the values were `true` before but now the user wants to unsubscribe). Hence, when the client sends `false` for any of these fields, the generator code serializer just omits these fields.

How do I achieve this and avoid the omission of these fields for the above scenario?

PS: I am using Javascript as my GRPC client and Python and GRPC Server.

Comment: This has now changed; see update to my answer

Answer (score 7):

Update: this has changed recently with the re-introduction of presence tracking info proto3 via a new meaning of the `optional` keyword:

```proto
message User {
   optional int64 id = 1;
   optional bool email_subscribed = 2;
   optional bool sms_subscribed = 3;
}
```

With this change (now available in protoc etc), explicit assignment is transmitted even if it is the implicit default value.

---

You cannot under proto3. Your best bet is probably to define a tri-bool enum with not-specified as the first item with value zero, and some true / false values after that.

This will require the same *space* as a protobuf `bool`, but will not be binary compatible - so you cannot simply change the declared member type on existing messages. Well, I guess if you make true === 1, then at least that still works - and for the transition you'd have to anticipate false / not specified being ambiguous until you've flushed any old data.

The other option is to add a `bool fooSpecified` member for every `bool foo`, but that takes more space and is error-prone due to being manual.

Comment: Can you share any example for your answer?

Comment: @Vijendra I can do better than that... give me a sec...

Answer (score 2):

Another option will be to use [wrappers](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto) with proto3. They basically wrap your value in a message so on the parent message it can be left null.

This way you can differentiate null / false / true on your bool field with a some extra work.